# While loop condition changed in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

The while loop condition I want to change is done by clicking on a button, while a second button continues the loop and adds to a counter. The problem is the code doesn't wait for jQuery to load and therefore creates an infinite loop. I wasn't able to use setInterval() because the code also includes counters for variables used elsewhere in my code.

```
var condition = true;
while(condition === true) {
    $('#modal').modal();
    $('#modalButton1').on('click', function() {
        variableCounter++;
    });
    $('#modalButton2').on('click', function() {
        condition = false;
    });
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Insted of $('#modalButton1').on('click', function() {
        variableCounter++;
    }); Try  $("#modalButton1").click(function() {
  variableCounter++;
});

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the `click` event handlers continuously in the `while` loop. Instead you should define the event handlers once in the document-ready section and then put the desired functionality (i.e. end the modal dialogue when button 2 was clicked) into the handler function for these click events.

```
$(function(){
  $('#modalButton1').on('click', function() { variableCounter++; });
  $('#modalButton2').on('click', function() { $('#modal').hide(); })
});
```

I don't know whether `.hide()` will achieve what you want. You should call the relevant function for shutting down your modal dialogue here.